# IONIC 4: Horizontal reorder list

Tags: ionic-framework

May anyone tell me if there is a way to implement an horizontal ion reorder list like this in Ionic 4?

[image]

I’ve followed this documentation, but it implements an ion reorder list in a vertical style, not horizontal:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/reorder-group

I need, not only to show the items on the list horizontally, but also to preserve the possibility for the user of rearranging them by drag and drop, for example:

[image]

May anyone suggest me a solution to do these two things?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you share how visually this should look like

Comment: @Sergey Rudenko Thank you for your reply! I've just edited my question

Comment: so yes out of box the reorder list is designed for vertical UX. If you need horizontal (reorder chained items) you can try use a library like dragula https://valor-software.com/ng2-dragula/ or actually do your own implementation (sounds scary but its not that hard). If what you shared is exactly the thing I could try share with you how would I do that later today

Comment: @Sergey Rudenko thank you very much for your help! What I've shared is exactly what I need. If you can show me how to implement this kind of reorder chained items in ionic via drag and drop, I am very grateful to you

Comment: Please check the answer and the code. It is on stackblitz and uses Ionic 3. But in this case there should be minimal difference for Ionic 4. If you have issues let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement it yourself if your case is simple. Here is Ionic 3 code:

https://ionic-vhxsmw.stackblitz.io

Editor URL:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-vhxsmw

I tried to leave some comments in there for you.

If your case is more complex or you do not want to learn low level implementation detail - maybe the best bet is Dragula library.

This implementation has some optimizations and should work for both touch and mouse.

It still may have some things you want to tweak. Let me know if you have questions

Comment: Thank you very much @Sergey Rudenko! That's what I needed!